# Access data from grid field in a related entry, linked by a grid field

Tags: ee2, relationships, grid

Not sure if that title makes sense, but here is the problem I'm having.

I have a grid field with four rows (`home-featured-lesson`). This grid field has one column, which is a relationship(`lesson-plan`). You select the entry you want to relate, then I pull data from that.

It mostly works, apart from one bit - I have another grid field in the related entry (`lesson-images`) and I can't seem to pull anything from it. Here is my code:

```
{home-featured-lesson}
    <div class="lesson-plan">
        {home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan:lesson-images}
            <p>{home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan:lesson-images:image}</p>
        {/home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan:lesson-images}

        <h3>{home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan:title}</h3>
        <p>{home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan:lesson-summary}</p>
    </div>
{/home-featured-lesson}
```

And here is my output:

```
<div class="lesson-plan">


    <h3>Lesson Plan 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="lesson-plan">


    <h3>Lesson Plan 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="lesson-plan">


    <h3>Lesson Plan 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="lesson-plan">


    <h3>Lesson Plan 4</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the tag pair for the grid field inside the related entry is not returning anything at all. I've tried a few variations on the tag pair but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **think** you're almost there.

```
{home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan}
    {home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan:lesson-images}
        <p>{home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan:lesson-images:image}</p>
    {/home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan:lesson-images}
{/home-featured-lesson:lesson-plan}
```

I think you need to establish the first relationship, then the 2nd. Can't do it in one go, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for that! Works perfectly. Guess I'd been staring at it for too long to realise I was missing a loop :P